# Add two languages for keyboard when building aosp

Tags: android-source, android-input-method, android-7.1-nougat, android-settings

I know if I want to set the default language of AOSP keyboard, I should go through my product Makefile and change default locale (that displayed in AOSP keyboard,too).

But what should I do to have two languages (i.e. Chinese and English) for my keyboard by default? So my user need not to add English for keyboard manually at first. (locale is Chinese)